# Help writing query for MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a MS SQL Server query statement that will generate the result set table name SUMMARY from the DETAIL table

```
Server name: Development
Database name: Test  

                  DETAIL            
STATE     Total BadEggs  GoodEggs   Unknown
Kansas      5      2        2         1
Texas       10     5        4         1
Texas       2      0        2         0
Georgia    20      5        5        10
Maine      25     15        5         5
Florida     5      1        2         2
Texas       8      4        2         2
Georgia     9      3        4         2
Maine       5      2        1         2
Florida    11      1        5         5
Texas       2      2        0         0
Florida     5      2        1         2
New York   20      5        5         10
New York    6      2        2         2
Alabama    10      3        4         3
Alabama    30     12       15         3
Alabama     4      1        1         2
Alabama     8      3        2         3
       185  



                  SUMMARY               
STATE     Total  BadEggs   GoodEggs Unknown
Kansas      5        2          2   1
Texas      22       11          8   3
Georgia    29        8          9   12
Maine      30       17          6   7
Florida    21        4          8   9
New York   26        7          7   12
Alabama    52       19          22  11
Total     185       68          62  55
```

Comment: Use `sum (column) .. group by STATE`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL([State],'Total'), SUM(Total), SUM(GoodEggs), SUM(BadEggs)
FROM Detail
GROUP BY
GROUPING SETS (([State]), ());
```

Although you should probably just do `GROUP BY [State]` and provide the total row and right column in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways :

```
-- test data

CREATE TABLE dbo.Details
    ([STATE]   varchar(10), [Total] int, [BadEggs] int, [GoodEggs] int, [Unknown] int)
;

INSERT INTO dbo.Details
VALUES
    ('Kansas', 5, 2, 2, 1),
    ('Texas', 10, 5, 4, 1),
    ('Texas', 2, 0, 2, 0),
    ('Georgia', 20, 5, 5, 10),
    ('Maine', 25, 15, 5, 5),
    ('Florida', 5, 1, 2, 2),
    ('Texas', 8, 4, 2, 2),
    ('Georgia', 9, 3, 4, 2),
    ('Maine', 5, 2, 1, 2),
    ('Florida', 11, 1, 5, 5),
    ('Texas', 2, 2, 0, 0),
    ('Florida', 5, 2, 1, 2),
    ('New York', 20, 5, 5, 10),
    ('New York', 6, 2, 2, 2),
    ('Alabama', 10, 3, 4, 3),
    ('Alabama', 30, 12, 15, 3),
    ('Alabama', 4, 1, 1, 2),
    ('Alabama', 8, 3, 2, 3)
;
```

-- generate the desired output

-- using ROLLUP

```
select ISNULL([State], 'Total') as [State]
,SUM(Total) as Total
,SUM(BadEggs) as BadEggs
,SUM(GoodEggs) as GoodEggs
,sum(unknown) as unknown
 from Details
 group by rollup([state])
```

-- USING CTE

```
    ;with cte
as (
    select [STATE]
        ,sum(Total) as Total
        ,sum(BadEggs) as BadEggs
        ,sum(GoodEggs) as GoodEggs
        ,sum(unknown) as unknown
    from dbo.Details
    group by [STATE]
    )
select *
from cte

union all

select 'Total'
    ,sum(Total) as Total
    ,sum(BadEggs) as BadEggs
    ,sum(GoodEggs) as GoodEggs
    ,sum(unknown)
from cte
```

-- without CTE

```
select [STATE], sum(Total) as Total, sum(BadEggs) as BadEggs, sum(GoodEggs) as GoodEggs, sum(Unknown)  as Unknown from dbo.Details
group by [STATE]
union all
select 'Total', sum(Total) as Total, sum(BadEggs) as BadEggs, sum(GoodEggs) as GoodEggs, sum(Unknown) from dbo.Details
```

For small tables above approache using CTE does not matter for performance. For big table, use WINDOWING functions.

A very good article is written by Aaron Bertrand : [Best approaches for running totals – updated for SQL Server 2012](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)